# Grunt can't find "compass.bat" binary

Tags: gruntjs, compass

When I try to execute the command:

```
grunt build
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Couldn't find the `compass.bat` binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've checked and I have ruby and compass properly installed on my computer and the ruby/bin is correctly indicated on the PATH variable. Both compass and ruby/gem are recognized by my console.

Can someone give me an hand?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017488